# why the next item in a list becomes disapeared after split in python

Tags: python, list, split, append

I got a list. Then, i want to detect any 'and' in the list, then i should split items between 'and' and put both into a new list.

The problem is, after i make a split, the next item will be disappeared from the list.
For instance, 
I got a list :

```
liss1=['a','b','c','d and e','f','g','h']
```

After split and removal the current item, the next item 'f' disappeared from the list as shown below:

```
item 0 a
item 1 b
item 2 c
item 3 d and e
item 4 g
item 5 h
Unique_liss ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd ', ' e', 'g', 'h']
```

This is my code:

```
liss1=['a','b','c','d and e','f','g','h']
Unique_liss=[]
for i,item in enumerate(liss1):
    print('item',i,item)
    if 'and' in item:
        liss1.remove(item)
        split_elem_dan = item.split('and')
        for s in split_elem_dan:
            Unique_liss.append(s)
    else:
         Unique_liss.append(item)
print()
print('Unique_liss',Unique_liss)
```

Does anyone has an idea on how to improve ?so that, the next item would be remained in the list

Comment: you don't need to remove the item

Comment: You are modifying the list while iterating. Try to make a copy of the list first and see if that fixes your issue. Or do a reverse iteration of the original list. Or just remove the ‘liss1.remove(item)’ line.

Comment: thank you both of you

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
for i,item in enumerate(liss1):
```

to

```
for i,item in enumerate(liss1.copy()):
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d and e','f','g','h']
res = []
for x in lst:
    if 'and' in x:
        res += [y.strip() for y in x.split('and')]
    else:
        res.append(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without the enumerate, this approach works:

```
liss1=['a','b','c','d and e','f','g','h']
Unique_liss=[]

for item in liss1:
  for letter in [s for s in item.split('and')]:
    Unique_liss.append(letter.strip())


print('Unique_liss',Unique_liss)
```

Answer (score -2):

I've edited your code to this

```
liss1 = ['a','b','c','d and e','f','g','h']
Unique_liss=[]
for i in range(len(liss1)-1):
    print('item',liss1[i])
    if 'and' in liss1[i]:
        split_elem_dan = liss1[i].split(' and ')
        for s in split_elem_dan:
            Unique_liss.append(s)
    else:
         Unique_liss.append(liss1[i])
print('\nUnique_liss : ',Unique_liss)
```

and the result is

```
item a
item b
item c
item d and e
item f
item g

Unique_liss :  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Comment: This only works for a single instance of 'and' in the list. It fails to work if there are 0 or more than 1.